# Conversion sql select query to array for json encode

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to make $sql to $employees which is array for `print` `json_encode($employees);`

```
$sql = "SELECT name,title,salary  FROM persons";
```

I have already tried with this code but result was right

```
$employees = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     $employees['name'] = $r['name'];
     $employees['title']=$r['title'];
     $employees['salary']=$r['salary'];

}
print json_encode($employees);
```

Please help to find output as like following this
Output:

```
$employees = 
    array(
            array
            (
            "name" => "Jack",
            "title" => "Magager",
            "salary" => "$60,000",
            ),

            array
            (
            "name" => "Joe",
            "title" => "Developer",
            "salary" => "$50,000",
            ),

            array
            (
            "name" => "Susan",
            "title" => "Marketer",
            "salary" => "$50,000",
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrides the `$employees` at each iteration of the loop, so you get only the last result. You have to **append** to array using `[]`. Then you could directly append the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` which returns an associative array:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, title, salary FROM persons";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$employees = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $employees[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($employees);
```

You also append a new created array:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, title, salary FROM persons";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$employees = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $employees[] = [
        'name' =>  $r['name'],
        'title' => $r['title'],
        'salary' => $r['salary']
    ];
}
print json_encode($employees);
```

Will outputs (reformatted):

```
[{"name":"Jack","title":"Magager","salary":"$60,000"},
 {"name":"Joe","title":"Developer","salary":"$50,000"},
 {"name":"Susan","title":"Marketer","salary":"$50,000"}]
```

---

**EDIT**

You will get a two dimensional array:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, title, salary FROM persons";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$employees = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $employees[] = $r;
}
```

`$employees` will contains:

```
 $employees = array(
     array(
         "name" => "Jack",
         "title" => "Magager",
         "salary" => "$60,000",
     ),
     array(
        "name" => "Joe",
        "title" => "Developer",
        "salary" => "$50,000",
     ),
     array(
        "name" => "Susan",
        "title" => "Marketer",
        "salary" => "$50,000",
     )
);
```

Comment: but i need this format $employees = 
    array(
            array
            (
            "name" => "Jack",
            "title" => "Magager",
            "salary" => "$60,000",
            ),

            array
            (
            "name" => "Joe",
            "title" => "Developer",
            "salary" => "$50,000",
            ),

            array
            (
            "name" => "Susan",
            "title" => "Marketer",
            "salary" => "$50,000",
            )
        );

Comment: i need this , $employees = array( array ( "name" => "Jack", "title" => "Magager", "salary" => "$60,000", ), array ( "name" => "Joe", "title" => "Developer", "salary" => "$50,000", ), array ( "name" => "Susan", "title" => "Marketer", "salary" => "$50,000", ) );

Comment: @Biddut So, just remove `print json_encode($employees);`. The `$employees` variable contains this.

Comment: sql query to two dimensional array

Comment: @Biddut I've updated the answer. Please, see the last part. `$employee` contains a two dimensional array, as you can see using `print_r()`.

Comment: @Biddut Please see the updated answer (edit part). Is that you want?

Comment: I do not need [0],[1],[2]

Comment: @Biddut 0,1,2 are explicit here. Your expected output in your question contains them implicitly. Because you can access to `echo $employees[0]['name']` will output: `Jack`.

Comment: Please remove   [0],[1],[2]

Comment: i need "name" ,but you have given [name]

Comment: @Biddut Please see this example : https://eval.in/983149 from your excepted array.